# Best way to remove lines from a file where matching text (not whole line) exists in another file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file of email addresses (file 1)
and another file (file 2) of lines of data that contain some of these email addresses

I want to compare files and remove all lines in file 2 that have a matching email in file 1.

I know I can do a loop and use `sed -i`
or loop and grep each line to a new file then compare files with COMM

But I was wondering if there is a comparison method that I can kind of grep all lines in file1 to file2 and just be left with the lines from file2 that do not contain any emails in file 1

file 1:

```
test@invalid.com
test2@invalid.com
test3@invalid.com
```

file 2:

```
23456|tom|jones|test@goodemailcom|10
12345|pete|best|pete@goodemail.com|10
87569|remove3|me3|test3@invalid.com|10
23098|mike|jones|mike@goodemailcom|10
10985|al|best|al@goodemail.com|10
09865|removve|me|test@invalid.com|10
13579|remove2|me2|test2@invalid.com|10
```

Appreciate any knowledge anyone has.

Comment: Ummm ... your example data has all info sitting on one line in both files, items space separated.  Is that intentional?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `fgrep` for this:

```
fgrep -v -f file1  file2  > unique_addresses
```

This task will be a lot easier if you have 1 email address per line in both files.

Traditionally `fgrep` exists as a separate program, but in GNU utilities, `grep -F` does the same thing.

Comment: For what it's worth, `-F` is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) and in no way limited to GNU. I remember using it on Solaris 10 as well.